# Setting up message for validation rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, validates-uniqueness-of

I have this validation rule:

```
  validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :format => {:with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => 'Email is not valid.'}, :uniqueness => true
```

and I would like to set up own message for

```
validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :format => {:with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => 'Email is not valid.'}, :uniqueness => {message: 'This email address has already been taken.'}
```

But this generate only the default message **has already been taken**, not the one I defined in the message part. How to customise it?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Rails are you using ? I tested your validation code on a Rails app running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.16 and it showed all the customized messages.